# Remove a commit from remote git history which I don't have locally

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-revert

A team member has accidentally committed over 1GB of files to our master branch and pushed it up to origin. I've since removed it from source control and committed to master. However, all other collaborators who are updating their code (via `git pull`) are actually downloading the files as part of the history.

I want to get rid of that commit entirely from history. I imagine this would be much easier to do if I had access to the team member's computer, but I don't at the moment. So is there a way to do this without having to pull down the latest from remote?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a copy of the repo, but just that you don't have the latest with the big commit. You can push your copy to the repo with a `git push -f` to completely override that other repo commit and continue from there.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I don't have that commit, so I want to avoid it as much as possible. Problem is she committed more code afterward, so would doing a `push -f` blow that away?

Comment: @john - of course. Now that is her job to make sure it gets pushed once the repo is in a proper state. The code will be blown away from the server, but will of course remain on her local repo and she must be able to rebase / pull and push.

Comment: I somehow managed to do a partial pull (`git pull origin master` followed by a `CTRL+C`). It didn't download the files, but got my history up to date. So I was able to do a `rebase` to get the commit out and `push -f` up to master.